# Updating matched array by identifier with multiple names

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a user model with the following schema

```
{
  _id: userId,
  inbox: {
    inbox: [Array of message documents],
    sent: [Array of message documents],
  }
}
```

Now i want to find and update a message in one of the arrays by the message _id but the document can be in either one.

If i try to reference the document after using the $or operator i get an error `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

Can/Should i even do it like that ?

Is there a better way ?

Should i just send whether the message is in inbox or sent ?

```
db.getCollection("users").findOneAndUpdate(
  { $or: [
      { 'inbox.sent._id': ObjectId("5cea292c8c03c800d43a8379") },
      { 'inbox.inbox._id': ObjectId("5cea292c8c03c800d43a8379") },
    ]
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'inbox.sent.$.inTrash': true ,
      'inbox.inbox.$.inTrash': true
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: It seems positionnal operator can't work with 2 differents arrays targeted in the filter. So yes you have to make two operations.

Comment: And in the case you care performance with big numbers of documents/subdocuments, take care of this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/  embedded arrays is a choice that must be studied deeply very soon to avoid surprises.